# Getting No data received for go language form

Tags: go

It's the simple form from astaxie's book 
 when I try '/login' , I get

```
No Data received { Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.   Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE }
```

Here's the code:

**main.go**

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

)

func sayhelloName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello astaxie!") // write data to response
}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
      t, err :=template.New("").Parse(loginHtml)
      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }

      const loginHtml = `
      <html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form action="/login" method="post">
          Username:<input type="text" name="username">
          Password:<input type="password" name="password">
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
      `

    }    else {
        r.ParseForm()
        // logic part of log in
        fmt.Println("username:", r.PostFormValue("username"))
        fmt.Println("password:", r.PostFormValue("password"))
    }
}


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayhelloName) // setting router rule
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
   http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil) // setting listening port

}

#login.gtpl
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/login" method="post">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username">
    Password:<input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Any idea??
```

Comment: Also thanks Leo for editing Q. I am noob here so was waiting for someone to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your original question (which has been edited several times) was that your `ParseFiles()` function failed, it was not able to read your template file. You didn't know about this because the `error` it returned you just discarded. *Never do that!* The least you can do is print the error or call `panic(err)` if it occurs. Would you have done that, you would have seen the cause immediately.

The `login.gtpl` file has to be placed in the working directory you start you app from if you specify a relative path. Or specify an absolute path.

You can also put your HTML source into your Go file like this until you sort things out:

```
t, err := template.New("").Parse(loginHtml)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
t.Execute(w, nil)
// ... the rest of your code


// At the end of your .go source file (outside of login() func) insert:
const loginHtml = `
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/login" method="post">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username">
    Password:<input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
`
```

**Note #1:**

Since your HTML template is just a static HTML, in its current form you can simply just send it to the output without building and executing a template from it:

```
// Instead of calling template.New(...).Parse(...) and t.Execute(...), just do:
w.Write([]byte(loginHtml))
```

**Note #2:**

The `Request.Form` is only available after `Request.ParseForm()` has been called, so do that prior to accessing it. Also for `POST` forms you might want to use `Request.PostForm` instead.

As an alternative you can use the [`Request.PostFormValue()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.PostFormValue) method which does this for you automatically if it has not yet been called:

```
fmt.Println("username:", r.PostFormValue("username"))
fmt.Println("password:", r.PostFormValue("password"))
```

Comment: It's in the same place as main.go {GOPATH/src/}

Comment: @RamanSM It has to be in the current folder you start your app from if you specify a relative path. See my edited answer.

Comment: @RamanSM Also please be kind to delete your comments here, I will do the same. To keep the question and answer clean.

Comment: gotta eat something ,will check later ( if someone posts something)

Comment: I put the `loginHtml` const outside of the `login()` func.

Comment: Yep!! It's working now. But why it was not working with template.ParseFiles??

Comment: Thanks ICZA !   I was losing hope. Was nearly thinking of  going to rOrails

Comment: Please edit the answer man . Also don't forget t.execute(w,nil)

Comment: what I mean is remove part above EDIT and add t.Execute(w,nil)

Comment: Still wondering why it wouldn't work with template.ParseFiles !!

Comment: @RamanSM I edited the answer. The original problem was that your `ParseFiles()` function call failed (returned an `error`), it wasn't able to parse your template file because it wasn't in the working directory (from where you started your app), and you silently discarded the error.