# Server thinks all requests have r.Method "GET"

Tags: http, go

Edit: solved! The server was redirecting from /whales to /whales/, which transformed the request into a GET. My curl command had the trailing slash, but my form and Postman request did not.

---

My basic server always has "GET" as r.Method, even for post requests from Postman and html forms. r.Form is always an empty map.

My code:

```
func whaleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Print(r.Method)
    fmt.Print(r.Form)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/whales/", whaleHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9002", nil))
}
```

And this prints:

```
GETmap[]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance, all!

---

Edit: everything works as expected with curl, but Postman and regular forms are still being treated like GET requests.

`curl -d "Name=Barry" -X POST http://localhost:9002/whales/`

results in:

`POSTmap[]`,

and `r.FormValue("Name")` spits out `Barry`

---

Sample form:

```
<form action="/whales" method="POST">
<div><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="Length" placeholder="Length"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="Type" placeholder="Type"></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Save"></div>
</form>
```

And full output from `fmt.Print(r)`, formatted a little for readability:

```
&{GET 
/whales/ 
HTTP/1.1 
1 
1 
map[
  Accept:[
    text/html,
    application/xhtml+xml,
    application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8
  ] 
  Accept-Language:[en-US,en;q=0.5] 
  Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] 
  Cookie:[io=08-aNjAMs8v6ntatAAAA] 
  Connection:[keep-alive] 
  Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:[1] 
  User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0] Referer:[http://localhost:9002/whales/create]
] 
{} 
<nil> 
0 
[] 
false 
localhost:9002 
map[] 
map[] 
<nil> 
map[] 
[::1]:61037 
/whales/ 
<nil> 
<nil> 
<nil> 
0xc420162400}
```

---

Edit: 
Sample Postman request, which results in r.Method => "GET"
[Posting with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMNZ9.png)

Comment: How are you generating the requests? Maybe show an example with curl?

Comment: This code should work correctly, the issue is somewhere outside the code (i.e. the client or some proxy between).

Comment: Aw dang, it works with curl:
`curl -d "Name=Barry" -X POST http://localhost:9002/whales/`

results in:

`POSTmap[]`

Comment: For some reason, Postman and html forms aren't going through the same way

Comment: Check for request type headers when you are sending using html form and PostMan

Comment: Thanks everyone, I added more samples.

Comment: You can use gorilla/mux to handle request for a pattern to a Method Type

Comment: Could it be that you're simply missing `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that Postman follows a redirect from /whales to /whales/ (note the trailing slash), thereby switching to GET. Check the output of `curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:9002/whales` to confirm the redirect.

Comment: @Peter that was it!!! Thank you so much!!!! It was redirecting to /whales/.

Comment: You can thank me by accepting my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You registered your handler under "/whales/", but your form action is "/whales" (without trailing slash). Go will redirect requests from /whales to /whales/ in this configuration -- most clients choose to follow via GET requests.

Either register the handler for "/whales", or change the form action to "/whales/", depending on other URLs you wish to handle. E.g., if you need to handle /whales/willy, leave the handler as-is and change the form action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`Request.ParseForm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) (or something that calls it indirectly, such as [`Request.FormValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue)), until then `Request.Form` will not contain form data. See possible duplicate [Getting No data received for go language form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610030/getting-no-data-received-for-go-language-form/28610108#28610108).

This is documented at `Request.Form`:

```
// Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL
// field's query parameters and the POST or PUT form data.
// This field is only available after ParseForm is called.
// The HTTP client ignores Form and uses Body instead.
Form url.Values
```

If you change your handler to this:

```
func whaleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.Method)
    fmt.Println(r.Form)
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing form:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r.Form)
}
```

And performing the `curl` command:

```
curl -d "Name=Barry" -X POST http://localhost:9002/whales/
```

Output will be:

```
POST
map[]
map[Name:[Barry]]
```